# After the state is updated, view in the "react-native-collapsible(Library)" section is getting distored in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-collapsible

I am using a "react-native-collapsible" library to display collapsible sections.
Each collapsible section contains the list of items, which can be deleted.

[image]

When I delete any item, the state is getting updated and the particular item is also getting removed, but it is distorting the view inside the section

[image]

**Can someone please tell how can i solve this.**

If I manually closes and opens the "January 23" section, the view is appearing correct.

[image]

But, I don't know how to do it using a code.

Below is the **relevant code** from **relevant files**:

**App.js**

```
const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState({}); // holds all the expenses objects 

function deleteExpenseHandler(updatedExpenses) { // updatedExpenses object comes from DeleteConfirmationModal.js
    setExpenses(updatedExpenses);
}

return (
    <>
        <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.expenseListContainer}>
                    <ExpenseList
                        months={twelveMonthsArr}
                        expenses={expenses}
                        displayDeleteConfirmaionModal={deleteConfirmaionModalVisibilityHandler} />
                </View>
            </View>
            <DeleteConfirmationModal
                expenseToDelete={expenseToDelete}
                expenses={expenses}
                visibility={deleteConfirmaionModalVisibility}
                deleteExpenseHandler={deleteExpenseHandler}
                closeModal={deleteConfirmaionModalVisibilityHandler} />
            <Toast />
    </>
);
```

**ExpenseList.js**

```
import Collapsible from 'react-native-collapsible';
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';


function ExpenseList(props) {
    const [activeSections, setActiveSections] = useState([]);
    const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(true);

    function setSections(sections) {
        setActiveSections(sections.includes(undefined) ? [] : sections);
    }

    function renderHeader(section, isActive) {
        const contentArray = section.content;

        let totalAmount = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
            totalAmount += Number(contentArray[i].amount);
        }


        return (
            <Animatable.View
                duration={400}
                style={[styles.header, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive, { flexDirection: 'row' }]}
                transition='backgroundColor'>
                <Text
                    style={[styles.headerText, { flex: 4, borderRightWidth: 2, borderRightColor: '#cccccc' }]}>
                    {section.title}
                </Text>
            </Animatable.View>
        );
    }

    function renderContent(section, isActive) {
        const contentArray = section.content;

        return (
            <Animatable.View
                duration={400}
                style={[styles.content, styles.active]}
                transition='backgroundColor'>
                {
                    contentArray.length == 0 ?
                        <Text style={styles.noExpensesText}>
                            No Expenses Present
                        </Text>
                        :
                        contentArray.map((content) => {
                            return (
                                <ExpenseItem
                                    key={content.id}
                                    id={content.id}
                                    date={content.date}
                                    displayDate={content.displayDate}
                                    month_year={content.monthName + '_' + content.year}
                                    date_month_year={content.date + '_' + content.monthName + '_' + content.year}
                                    text={content.text}
                                    icon={content.icon}
                                    amount={content.amount}
                                    displayDeleteConfirmaionModal={props.displayDeleteConfirmaionModal} />
                            );
                        })
                }
            </Animatable.View>
        );
    }

    // Final format required by 'react-native-collapsible' library  
    const finalExpensesArray = [
        {
            title: 'January 23',
            content: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    date: '23 Dec, 23',
                    text: 'This is dummy text.',
                    amount: '150',
                },
                // .....Objects of other dates of month 'January 23'
            ],
        },
        // .....Objects of other months
    ];

    return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
            <Collapsible collapsed={isCollapsed}>
                <View style={{ padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
                    <Animatable.Text
                        animation={isCollapsed ? undefined : 'zoomIn'}
                        duration={300}
                        useNativeDriver>
                        {/** There was value here in the example, but don't know where it's shown. Therefore, kept it blank. */}
                    </Animatable.Text>
                </View>
            </Collapsible>
            <Accordion
                align='bottom'
                activeSections={activeSections}
                sections={finalExpensesArray}
                touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
                expandMultiple={false}
                renderHeader={renderHeader}
                renderContent={renderContent}
                duration={400}
                onChange={setSections}
                renderAsFlatList={false} />
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

Comment: Add some code along with your example images.

Comment: @StenMuchow I have updated my question with more description. Thank you for showing interest.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this error, I solved this problem by removing style={{flex:1}} in my code in renderContent section.

> Before

[image]

```
  renderContent={item => (
        <View style={{
          flex: 1, // I am talking about this flex:1
          backgroundColor: 'grey',
          padding: 10
        }}>
          {
            item.id === 0 && <BusinessInformation editMode={editMode} />
          }

          <View style={styles.editButtonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => setEditMode(!editMode)}
              style={styles.editButtonView}
            >
              <Icon source={'pencil'} size={18} />
              <Text>{editMode ? 'Save Changes' : 'Edit Details'}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
```

After

[image: enter code here]